# Yii2 kartik\daterange\DateRangePicker not working in On Focus

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, kartik-v

I am using kartik\daterange\DateRangePicker

```
 echo '<div class="input-group drp-container period_time_line">';
                                            echo DateRangePicker::widget([
                                                'name' => 'BriefRequirements[requirement_value][]',
                                                'id' => 'period_txt',
                                                'useWithAddon' => true,
                                                'convertFormat' => true,
                                                'startAttribute' => 'from_date',
                                                'endAttribute' => 'to_date',
                                                'pluginOptions' => [
                                                    'locale' => ['format' => 'Y-m-d'],
                                                ],
                                            ]);
                                            echo '</div>';
```

It is working fine, but it is working only on click of the textbox not working in onfocus. ex if i press the tab in keyboard on selection of that field is not working

ID is assigned perfectly, please see the image below[image]

Comment: I am just wondering nobody knows the solution?

Comment: Have you try something? show us...nobody try to code for you....

Answer (score 0):

You can catch event when field get's focused and simulate click (jQuery).

```
$( "#your-date-range-picker" ).focusin(function() {
    $(this).trigger();
});
```

And you must configure id properly:

```
'options' => [
    'id' => 'period_txt'
]
```

Comment: its not working.. nothing showing.. tried the follow $( "#period_txt" ).focusin(function() {
                            $(this).trigger();
                        });

Comment: Your configuration is wrong in view file.
You initialize 'id' like this:
'options' => ['id' => 'period_txt']
I've changed it in main post.

Comment: I tried, like what you said but that is also not working... anyway ID is sets in the previous type. anyway in inspect element it is like this<input type="text" id="period_txt" class="form-control" name="BriefRequirements[requirement_value][]" data-krajee-daterangepicker="daterangepicker_dce876c6">

Comment: Hmm, that is weird, because if it works on click, this code is doing only that when field gets in focus it simulates click on that field. Can you try with $('#period_txt').trigger() on console?